# Round Integer Value in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I want to get following result in SQL Query.

If number is 121 then query should return me 130

If number is 125 then query should return me 130

If number is 128 then query should return me 130

If number is 130 then query should return me 130

If number is 137 then query should return me 140

If number is 140 then query should return me 140

Comment: Please provide the code you are trying.

Comment: Great choice when you have built-in ROUND, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need the `floor()` function when you're dealing with integer math.

```
(num + 9) / 10 * 10
```

Or you can think of it as finding the tens complement and adding that to the original number.

```
num + (10 - num % 10) % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FLOOR` function with some math, something like this

```
select floor((121 + 9) / 10) * 10; --130
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ffa43/25)

Answer (score 0):

You need [ROUND(number, -1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

> ROUND - Rounds a positive or negative value to a specific length and accepts three values:
>
> Value to round
>
> Positive or negative number
>
> This data type can be an int (tiny, small, big), decimal, numeric, money or smallmoney
>
> Precision when rounding
>
> Positive number rounds on the right side of the decimal point
>
> **Negative number rounds on the left side of the decimal point**
>
> Truncation of the value to round occurs when this value is not 0 or not included

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1829)**

```
SELECT 
    num
    ,[rounded] = ROUND(num, -1)
FROM (VALUES (121), (125), (128), (130), (137), (140)) AS tab(num)
```